# How to Test Facebook login via Cypress in web

Tags: facebook, testing, automation, cypress, facebook-login

I was trying to automate testing Facebook login feature on my website using **CYPRESS**.

I was not able to get my control to the Facebook login window that opens on clicking log in button on my website.

[image]

How should I get my cypress control to this window to proceed???

Cypress version: 7.7.0